# Show and Hide div (with some delay) using setInterval (no loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want this function to show div after a time interval and then hide it after some time with no looping

```
function myfun(){
            setInterval(function(){$("#welcome").show(100)}, 2000);
            setInterval(function(){$("#welcome").hide(500)}, 7000);
            }
```

but from this function it generates a infinite loop

can anyone help me

Comment: err.. setInterval will run your code in intervals as the name suggests.. You're probably looking for setTimeout instead

Comment: thanks that worked made a sly mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `setTimeout()` for this purpose,

```
function myfun(){
   setTimeout(function(){$("#welcome").show(100)}, 2000);
   setTimeout(function(){$("#welcome").hide(500)}, 7000);
}
```

`setInterval()` would invoke the supplied code for every time interval that you gave.